# Pre-creating a Path that depends on View width and height

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have a custom `View` that draws a complex `Path`. The dimensions of path elements are calculated using the view width and height.
I need a way to pre-create this path before `onDraw` is called to "Avoid object allocations during draw/layout...", in a moment when the view width and height are already known.
What is the proper moment in the View lifecycle to do such pre-creation?

Comment: pskink, make this an answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just override `View.onSizeChanged` and do your initialization there